# Why catch output as a template literal different from as a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I was wondering why the following outputs are seen based on each scenario:

Assume i have a route with the following code:

```
app.get("/tasks", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tasks = await Task.find({});
    res.send(tasks)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(`${e}`)
  }
```

Notice the last line in catch where i send the error, if I just type res.send(e) without the template literals a whole list of errors is generated with alot of errors.

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"5ef23a969ba85e6fa63\"",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "5ef23a969ba85e6fa63",
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {}
}
```

BUT,  if I use res.send(`${e}`) ( put the error as a literal) A simple line is generated with summary of the error.
`CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5ef23a969ba85e6fa63" at path "_id" for model "Task"`

Is it a feature of template literals or.. ?

Comment: No. It's a feature of `send()`. The template literal is nothing different from `….send(String(e))`, and `Error.prototype.toString()` usually takes the error's `message` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body parameter of `send(parameter)` can be :

- a Buffer object
- a String
- an object
- an Array

  ```
    res.send(Buffer.from('whoop'))
    res.send({ some: 'json' })
    res.send('<p>some html</p>')
    res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!')
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' })
  ```

The template literal transforms your object into `String` : `${e}` is a string.